# Long running or debugging time in c#

Tags: c#

My program contains thousands of lines.while debugging the program it will spend more time at last it show an exception 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll "Parameter is not valid." -Picture Box control.some time it show the exception "memory overload".
I am not understanding why it is long debugging time.
Can any one help me?

The problem occurred only when including this statement (when creating the Form's object in custom user control): 
    Form1 mainfrm = new Form1();

Comment: Well obviously you have some faulty parameters.

Comment: There are a number of problems that could be causing this. Without seeing some code examples, it is difficult to answer your question specifically.

Comment: Pesky faulty parameters. It'd be really helpful if you shared your code and told us where/when/what error you were getting. We may need to replicate your conditions to replicate the error and help you debug.

Comment: this.pictureBox2.Image = global::ALMALKIMOBI.Properties.Resources.l1;

Comment: That's just being a code tease. C'mon - share a little more!

Comment: the problem is arise (when creating the Form's object in custom user control): Form1 mainfrm = new Form1();

Answer (score 0):

Excessive delays during debugging followed by an out-of-memory exception often indicate that there is infinite recursion. Of could you would have to share the code to be sure, but that's where I'd check first.